# Is there a rapid online access to "feste Nomen-Präposition bzw. -Verb Verbindungen"?

Tags: idiom, noun, preposition, grammatical-case, dictionary

Is it me, or is it difficult to find *online*, in dictionaries and so on, all the information about a "feste Nomen-Präposition Verbindungen"?

Suppose you are writing in German and, for sake of concreteness, you need the expression *lack of*. You know the noun *Mangel* and autocompleting tells you that it goes with *an*, but you (as I actually did) don't remember the case that *an* induces.

To find out the case you might google *feste Nomen-Präposition Verbindungen* and eventually find a nice list of them by PONS in PDF: *Mangel an* —as many others, and that's the point of the question— isn't  there.

So you google *Mangel an* and don't find in the first pages anything, until you have to deduce from some text by Mr. Nobody, the correct case (und zwar `Dativ`). And you lost five minutes solely in deducing the preposition for *Mangel* and its case. Just for this tiny expression. And if you want to write good German, you might want to enrich your text with some *Redewendungen*, *Nomen-Verb Verbindungen* etc., which will you take five minutes each.

At the risk of sounding trite,

- what could a German-learner do to deal faster with this kind of fixed expressions?
- Why do wonderful (or standard) dictionaries, like  *Duden*, *dict.cc*, *wiktionary* only show "Mangel an" with no information about the case?

---

Ok, I must say that Langenscheidt's "Powerwörterbuch" has the needed info.

Comment: As for the second question, this usually means that the dictionary targets Germans (subconsciously, perhaps).

Comment: @chirlu That's the point. Why does a dictionary German-whatever-German target Germans?

Comment: I'd expect because it is prepared by Germans, who may not even be aware of the issue. I own a dictionary SV/DE/SV from a Swedish publisher, and it suffers from this very problem (targeting Swedish native speakers). For monolingual dictionaries as well, you can easily tell whether they are made for locals or for language learners.

Answer (score 3):

[Leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Mangel%20an&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) mentions dativ as necessary case for *Mangel an* in the first hit of the result list.

Comment: And so does [pons](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=mangel+an&l=deen&in=&lf=en), my favorite dictionary for translations. Interestingly the information is hidden when you look up in the ["German as foreign-language"-section](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=mangel&l=dedx&in=&lf=)