# Which preposition goes with "Aufsatz"?

Tags: difference, preposition

Which preposition goes with *Aufsatz*? Is it *über* or *zu*?

> Ein Aufsatz über die Kolonialisierung von Namibia?
>   Ein Aufsatz zu der Kolonialisierung von Namibia?

They seem to be similar but are there any subtle differences between the two.?

Comment: The topic is given with _über_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be easily found in dictionaries or other reference material (e.g., on [Wortschatz](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=1573306), _über_ is the most common right neighbour by far).

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8089/is-there-a-rapid-online-access-to-feste-nomen-praposition-bzw-verb-verbindung it may not be so easy to find in some dictionaries.

Comment: @chirlu: Per an answer below, "both are grammatically correct, but there is a subtle difference." This indicates that the question is not trivial and therefore not off-topic. I added a line to the question about subtle differences.

Comment: In beiden Fällen wäre der Genitiv besser: zur/über die Kolonialisierung Namibias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but there is a subtle difference:

- By using *über* you imply that the essay is covering the whole subject in general. This would be suitable for a descriptive summary aiming at people who are new to the subject.
- With *zu*, the essay becomes more like a contribution to the subject. It may contain comments, critiques and own discoveries.

Please note also that *zu* is commonly fused with the following article:

```
zu der -> zur
zu dem -> zum
```

Answer (score 0):

Ein Aufsatz über can be translated as "an essay **over**..." That is covering the topic in a "general" mannner.

Ein Aufsatz zu can be translated as "an essay **regarding**..." That is making a point (or two) about the topic.

Either can be used, but the correct usage depends on the context.